# routeChangeStart resume navigation with equivalent to $state.go

Tags: angularjs, ngroute, route-provider, angularjs-ng-route

I have to make an authorization validation during event `routeChangeStart` in an angular app, and the method to do it is a promise-based one. So I tried using `event.preventDefault()`, but I don't know a way to resume the navigation once the authorization service returns if user is authorized or not for that route. 
I need something equivalent to the `$state.go` from ui-router, but I still need to keep using the `$routeProvider` from angular. Is there some method or something else I am missing? Or a workaround to implement this some other way?

Edit: some of the code

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
        if (next.access) {
            event.preventDefault();
            authorization.authorize(next.access.allowAnonymous, next.access.permissions, next.access.permissionCheckType)
                .then(function (authorized) {
                    if (!authorized) {
                        next.$$route.templateUrl = "notauthorized.html";
                        next.$$route.controller = null;
                    } else { 
                        //resume???
                    }
                });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: I just added it. As you see it's pretty straightforward: I have to stop the navigation before calling the service and then redirect or resume depending on authorization result. Problem is how to resume navigation from promise callback.